# Remove body's background image from div

Tags: css

I have a `background-image` for `body`. I want remove this background image in the `div`s.

Is it possible with CSS only?

I tried with

```
div{
  background-image:none;
}
```

Comment: Give the divs a backgroundcolor e.g. white.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML elements have a transparent background by default. So if you simply want to cover body's background you can set a background to the `div` like that:

```
div {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

This works like covering a photo with a piece of paper.

Comment: Was just about to submit almost exactly the same thing :)